# Is it possible to load content of page without Refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Actually i want to refresh my content of a page without Refreshing the whole page through JavaScript or j Query ....... and i did my whole project into ( Php or javaScript) so i face such type of problem

**Note :** i want to refresh my page content when user do some action
[image: here is the screenshot of the page i want to load these dynamic boxes without loading the whole page]

Here is my Code:

//On Button click, the below will be execute:

```
  $('body').on('click', '#click', loadDoc);
```

and the LoadDoc functio:

```
   function loadDoc() { 

                                //alert('heruybvifr');
                var _this = $(this); 
                var order_id= $(this).parents('.modal').find('.order-id').text(); 

                $.get('myPHP.php',{order_id: order_id},function(){ 
             _this.hide();

                }) 
                }
```

Now myPHP.php :

```
  <?php
 include("connection.php");
 $limit = intval($_GET['order_id']);

echo $valuek;
    $query="UPDATE orders
SET status ='cooking'
 WHERE id = $limit";
if (mysqli_query($connection,$query)) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
 }


  ?>
```

Comment: Sure, use AJAX to pull in the new data then use that data to replace what is in your DOM.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Use the DOM, Luke.

Comment: "*through JavaScript or jQuery*" jQuery is a JavaScript library. If you use the jQuery library, you're also using JavaScript. They aren't two different languages. JavaScript is the *language*, jQuery is the library/layer. Just thought I'd point that out since you seem pretty new. See [jQuery.com](https://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use the `jQuery.ajax()` call.  Like this:
Change the text of a  element using an AJAX request:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

See this tutorial for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery Ajax functions to accomplish your requirement.
all there functions given below will work for loading the content without refreshing the page.

```
    $.post("/controller/function", params, function(data) {
        // set received data to html
    });

$.ajax("/controller/function", params, function(data) {
        // set received data to html
    });

$.get("/controller/function", params, function(data) {
        // set received data to html
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data from the server and and place the returned HTML into the  matched element.

```
<div id="content"></div>

$("#content").load( "ajax/test.html" );
```