# php div refresh without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm a newbie to php. How can i refresh a `div` container on the page without reloading the whole page?

I don't want to have the flicker when the reload is done. It looks more elegant if the `div` container refreshes. In the `div` container I show a text changing at different times per day. I would really appreciate your help here.

Example of the `div` container:

```
<?php
    if (date('w') == 6) {
      if (date('H') >= 5 && date('H') < 7) { ?>
         <div style="position: fixed; top: 45px; width: 100%">
           <table style="background-color: #0307f6;" width="100%">
             <tr style="background-color: #0307f6;">
               <td align="center" style="color: #FFF;" width="100%">ACTUALLY : lorem ipsum </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </div>
<?php  
       }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Use `ajax`.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to load content of page without Refreshing the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866519/is-it-possible-to-load-content-of-page-without-refreshing-the-whole-page)

Answer (score 1):

Like Eddie already said, use ajax. That means that your HTML will make a request (ask for information) to your PHP code. Your PHP code will then "reply" with the requested information and your HTML code can then use that to render the page.

With AJAX, all that happens in the background and the user will not see anything, meaning no flickering.

This was a SUPER simple explanation to get you introduced to the idea.

Check here for a basic intro:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Also, someone else already asked a similar question. Try to check that before asking the same thing again ;)

Check this post:
[Change DIV content using ajax, php and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery)