# How to redirect page to href link on click without page load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I am trying to redirect my php page to another php page without page load.

And these jQuery methods i have tried

1.This returns me alert but not redirecting to the page

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
$('a').click(function (event) 
{ 
   event.preventDefault(); 

   var url = $(this).attr('href');
 
   $.get(url, function(data) {
     alert(data);

    });

 });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>AJax</title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>


<a href="http://localhost:8001/Test/redirect.php"><h1>Click Here</h1></a>

</body>
</html>
```

2.This method is redirecting to the page but its getting load

```js
$('a').click(function (event) 
{ 
   event.preventDefault(); 

   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $.get(url, function(data) {
window.location.href="http://localhost:8001/Test/redirect.php"
    });

 });
```

I want a simple solution to redirect my page without getting load using jQuery and AJAX.
Guide me to achive this :)

Comment: This question is very confusing. You want to redirect the user to another page, but without loading the page? These two things are mutually exclusive. By definition, if you redirect the user to a page, that page is going to be loaded.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, but it's impossible to change pages without loading the next page. How else will the content be rendered if you don't load it at least once?

Comment: I have seen on several websites the content and the url is getting changed but page is not getting load but a loader gif shows untill the page load

Comment: may be this would help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866519/is-it-possible-to-load-content-of-page-without-refreshing-the-whole-page

Comment: in this solution url is remains same i want a solution where url is also redirect but page didnt load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear about what you want to achieve, but as I understood

- You want to load data to a page without changing the page
- You want to change the URL in the browser address bar without loading another page

If I'm right about your intention, then you have to

1. Use AJAX to get the data (like `$.get()`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
2. Use `window.history.pushstate()` (more on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

So, implementing it with your functions may look like this:

```
$('a').click(function (event) { 
   event.preventDefault(); 

   var url = $(this).attr('href');

   $.get(url, function(data) {
     // alert(data);
      window.history.pushState('stateObject', 'New Title', '/newpage')

      // code to display/render your new page content
      // supposing data holds valid HTML
      document.getElementById('content-container').innerHTML = data
    });
 });
```

In a sense you would like to create a `router` that loads your data, so I would point you towards using a **jQuery router**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jqueryrouter

Comment: I want to redirect to another page but not want to load the page as u can see this page where if you select any category the url is getting change also page is not getting load .https://gem-bead.com/gembead/gemstones/gemstones.html after any selecttion u will see url is getting change to https://gem-bead.com/gembead/gemstones/gemstones.html?gemstone_colo=5505

Comment: That's exactly what I discussed in my answer - data loading, URL changing and no page load

Comment: But  the new page redirect.php is not getting load its just changing my url plz see links i have shared

Comment: What IS `redirect.php`? Is it an API endpoint, so it sends some response (like data) to the frontend?

Comment: Ok got it 
it seems working on general php i am going to try this solution in magento 2 
thanks :)

Comment: Instead of assigning data to div tag we can simply use $("body").html(data);
also :)

Comment: @SayyedHasan technically you’re right, but that way you refresh all elements on the page, including static parts, like a header menu, and that’s not efficient and may cause worse user experience.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean change URL without refreshing, you can try this :

```
window.history.pushState('data','title','/test')
```